# Memcached: Timeout waiting for value: waited 10,000 ms. Node status: Connection Status ip:port active: true, authed: true, last read: 7,060,231ms ago

Tags: java, kubernetes, memcached

Facing memcached issue while running a application in K8 and memcached is running in docker.
[image]

Earlier we were in docker both application and memcached. Now we have migrated only application from docker to K8 but memcached is still running in docker.
After the application K8 migration we are not able to connect to memcached, we are getting time out exception. Tried doing telnet from K8 server, telnet is working fine.
Any possible guess on the issue?